# isOrientationSupported is deprecated in IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am getting this error and i have no idea how to fix it..

```
WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0xad482c0> isOrientationSupported] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -isVideoOrientationSupported
```

however when I look at the apples [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it says that it is a Mac OS function.. not IOS... so I am a bit confused...  looking forward get some answers.. Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AVCaptureConnection` is available also for iOS [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009522). You probably looked in the wrong documentation.

Answer (score 26):

Some sample code which works on pre-6.0 as well:

```
if ([captureVideoPreviewLayer respondsToSelector:@selector(connection)])
{
    if ([captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection isVideoOrientationSupported])
    {
        [captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
    }
}
else
{
    // Deprecated in 6.0; here for backward compatibility
    if ([captureVideoPreviewLayer isOrientationSupported])
    {
        [captureVideoPreviewLayer setOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
    }                
}
```

Comment: Instead of: self.interfaceOrientation which is UIInterfaceOrientation, you should be using AVCaptureVideoOrientation.

Answer (score 1):

The above answered sample code works fine. But need to replace self. interfaceOrientation with AVCaptureVideoOrientation.

Edited code as follows.

```
if ([captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection isVideoOrientationSupported])
{
    [captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
}
```

Depending on the requirement the orientation will be as portrait or landscape.

Edits and suggestions are welcomed.